# How to use directive on data value?

Tags: angular, angular-directive

How can I use a directive on a data value?

```
<div class="col-12 data" appPhoneNumber>
    {{data.phoneNumber}}
</div>
```

appPhoneNumber is my directive, and data.phoneNumber is the value I want to use it on. I tried it this way, but I am getting an error:

`Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[PhoneNumberDirective -> NgControl]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[PhoneNumberDirective -> NgControl]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for NgControl!`

I'm kind of at a loss here, I don't have much experience with directives

Edit to include directive code:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appPhoneNumber]'
})
export class PhoneNumberDirective {

  constructor(public ngControl: NgControl) { }
  @Input('appPhoneNumber') appPhoneNumber;

  @HostListener('ngModelChange', ['$event'])
  onModelChange(event) {
    this.onInputChange(event);
  }

  onInputChange(event){
    let newVal = event.replace(/\D/g, '');
    if(newVal.length === 0){
      newVal = '';
    } else if(newVal.length<=3){
      newVal = newVal;
    } else if(newVal.length<=6){
      newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})/, '$1.$2');
    } else if(newVal.length<=10){
      newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/, '$1.$2.$3');
    } else {
      newVal = newVal.substring(0, 10);
      newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/, '$1.$2.$3');
    }
    this.ngControl.valueAccessor.writeValue(newVal);
  }
}
```

Comment: what is this directive supposed to do? where's the code for it?

Comment: you should use the ```@Directive``` annotation and specify an ```@Input``` that has the same name. ```@Directive({ selector: '[appPhoneNumber]' })``` and then ```@Input('appPhoneNumber') appPhoneNumber;``` in the directive's class declaration.

Comment: @hilnius I tried using Input, but it still gives me the same error

Comment: @bryan60 updated. It's just supposed to add dots for phone numbers. Like this: xxx.xxx.xxxx

Comment: In inputs or just as display values?

Comment: @bryan60 Well ideally both. I'm using it for inputs at the moment, and trying to also use it for displaying values

Comment: can't do both with one directive, need a pipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't use an input control with ngControl injected without an angular input, that's why you're getting the no provider error.  for simple display values you need a pipe. First extract your transform function into something reusable:

```
function formatPhoneNumber(val) {
    let newVal = val.replace(/\D/g, '');
    if(newVal.length === 0){
      newVal = '';
    } else if(newVal.length<=3){
      newVal = newVal;
    } else if(newVal.length<=6){
      newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})/, '$1.$2');
    } else if(newVal.length<=10){
      newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/, '$1.$2.$3');
    } else {
      newVal = newVal.substring(0, 10);
      newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/, '$1.$2.$3');
    }
    return newVal;
}
```

and put that to work in your directive, then write a pipe that uses it as well:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'phone'})
export class PhonePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string): string {
    return formatPhoneNumber(value);
  }
}
```

declare / import it as normal then use it like so:

```
<div class="col-12 data">
    {{data.phoneNumber | phone}}
</div>
```

Comment: Would I be able to use a pipe for both inputs and displaying values? Or will I have to create both a directive and a pipe no matter what?

Comment: you need a pipe for display data and a directive for formatting inputs. They are fundamentally different, best you can do is pull the actual formatting function out and use  it in both places as recommended.